# My laptop WiFi is very slow with downloads, what can it be?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

On my laptop, the built-in WiFi started being very slow - on a **20Mbps** internet connection, I usually get something like **0.5Mbps**. Interesting is that upload speeds are OK (~20Mbps). I tried to connect to my router using a cable and that solves the issue, I tried an external WiFi adapter and it also worked fast so it has to be something with my built-in WiFi adapter.

But, I was thinking, if it were dead, it would be dead and I could not connect at all, right? What is weird that the connection is working but very very slow.

What can I try? Can something like Connectify-me has something to do with it? I tried to reset its settings it and it's still the same.

Is there a settings somewhere in Windows that could limit my WiFi speed?

Answer (score 1):

i assume you put your laptop very near to your router.

first, i would try to install the newest drivers for your wifi interface.

second, 
you could try to rule out if it is a hardware issue, by downloading for example an ubuntu live-cd, burning it to a cd and booting from it. ubuntu has good built in support for drivers for notebooks and with a bit of luck wifi should work with it out of the box. 
then i would try to run a download/bandwith test, either with wget on the command line or by googling bandwith test.

Comment: Live CD is a good tip, will try to do that.